# How to add a gnome-terminal desktop entry to pantheon-files shell

Tags: linux, gnome-terminal

I added this desktop entry in /usr/share/applications which resulted in this :(picture) in pantheon-files :

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=myTerminal
TryExec=gnome-terminal
Exec=gnome-terminal -w %u
Icon=utilities-terminal
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
X-GNOME-Gettext-Domain=gnome-terminal
NoDisplay=true
MimeType=inode/directory;
```

unfortunately it does not work, what can I change so that i can open selected item (by right click) (usually a directory) in gnome terminal
PS : I am using linux mint 18 Sarah, and using panteon-files which I prefer to nemo. 
[image]

Comment: Try one of the following: `Exec=gnome-terminal -w %f` or `-w %d` or `-w %n`

Comment: all 3 options are not working

Comment: Well, i am not surprised... i do not have the same set up to make more tests. When i used Nautilus i was using nautilus actions pkg which provide right click context menu customization.Nemo has its own nemo actions package. You could try it as a work around : https://grvj.wordpress.com/2014/01/19/adding-new-items-in-right-click-context-menu-in-linux-mint-cinnamon/